# Get the branch name of a tip commit

Tags: git

I have a commit SHA id, and I want to know if it is the tip (head) of a branch, and if it is, I want to know what branch it is.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below command to see if the commit is at the tip and also name of the branch.

```
git show-ref | grep <commit-id>
```

**Example:**

```
git show-ref | grep ed6ec82243a82059dd28c3e7c353e4d35e400a85
ed6ec82243a82059dd28c3e7c353e4d35e400a85 refs/heads/r34.0.0
ed6ec82243a82059dd28c3e7c353e4d35e400a85 refs/remotes/origin/r34.0.0
```

r34.0.0 is the branch name, which shows both local and remote repository's .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your `.git/refs/heads` directory. It will list each head as a separate file, each file contains the SHA hash of the commit.

Comment: Use `git show-ref` or `git for-each-ref`, not direct raw access, otherwise you'll miss "packed" refs (in `.git/packed-refs`).